# How to modify function so that matches are appended in new line?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple function that looks through column A against column C to find matches, and append them separated by a semi-colon.

```
Sub Adrift()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = Cells(I, "A").Value
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(Cells(J, "C").Value, v) > 0 Then
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

My goal is to change this line `v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value` so that any matches beyond the first, is separated by a carriage return. So the expected results would look like:

[image]

**EDIT: Expected Result Based on Actual Data**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The logic of `InStr(Cells(J, "C").Value, v)` is not good. Sku `foo` matches not only `foo.jpg` but also `foo3.jpg`.
- If there isn't matches, the cell on ColB is blank. eg. sku `foo4`
- Note: if the data table is huge, loading Col A and C into an array improves the efficiency.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastA As Long, lastC As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, aImg
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For j = 2 To lastC
        sKey = Split(Split(Cells(j, "C").Value, ".")(0), "-")(0)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & Cells(j, "C").Value
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = Cells(j, "C").Value
        End If
    Next j
    ReDim arrRes(1 To lastC, 1)
    iR = 0
    For i = 2 To lastA
        sKey = Trim(Cells(i, "A").Value)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                aImg = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
                For j = 0 To UBound(aImg)
                    iR = iR + 1
                    If j = 0 Then arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                    arrRes(iR, 1) = aImg(j)
                Next
            Else
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Cells(2, 1).Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update: revise code for OP's real data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim lastA As Long, lastC As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, aImg, arrA, arrC
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    Dim iLoc1 As Long, iLoc2 As Long
    lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Load data
    arrA = Range("A1:A" & lastA).Value
    arrC = Range("C1:C" & lastC).Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through image col
    For i = 1 To lastC
        sKey = arrC(i, 1)
        If Len(sKey)>0 Then
            iLoc1 = InStr(1, sKey, "-", vbTextCompare)
            iLoc2 = InStr(1, sKey, "_", vbTextCompare)
            If iLoc1 + iLoc2 = 0 Then
                sKey = Split(sKey, ".")(0)
            Else
                If Len(sKey) - Len(Replace(sKey, "-", "")) > 1 Then
                    iLoc2 = InStrRev(sKey, "-", , vbTextCompare)
                ElseIf iLoc2 = 0 Then
                    iLoc2 = InStrRev(sKey, ".", , vbTextCompare)
                End If
                sKey = Left(sKey, iLoc2 - 1)
            End If
            ' Consolidate by sku name
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrC(i, 1)
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrC(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To lastC, 1)
    iR = 0
    ' Loop through sku name
    For i = 1 To lastA
        sKey = Trim(arrA(i, 1))
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                aImg = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
                For j = 0 To UBound(aImg)
                    iR = iR + 1
                    If j = 0 Then arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                    arrRes(iR, 1) = aImg(j)
                Next
            Else
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Add new sheet and write output
    Sheets.Add ' optional
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

- The code can handle different patterns. Please validate the output before using it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like the idea of using an array, because the data set can sometimes be huge. For some reason when running the function I don't see any results. Here is the sample file: https://file.io/0Gf2xVwXCL1s

Comment: The pattern of real data is different with the sample data in your post. `-` is part of sku name. The image names have different pattern. `109-63-CPL.png` `1090-AGB_800.png` The delimeter fo last part is different. Is there any rules to identify the sku name for image file?

Comment: Basically the string **before** the first `-` should be looked against column C, if they match, then ideally I'd do one more match with the string **after** the first `-`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please show what's the expected result for `H101101-OB` 
`H101102-AGB` in your post. I don't think you need double matching.

Comment: Ok I added. FYI the original script does work in matching these, any additonal matches are appended after a `;`

Comment: As the comment in my answer that the original script has a bug. I moved your screenshot to original post. It's easy for SO users follow up. I've posted the revised code.

Comment: I'm actually receiving an error on this line `sKey = Split(sKey, ".")(0)` -- says it's "Error: 9, subscript out of range" -- Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: I tried using `vbNewLine` on this line `v2 = v2 & vbNewLine & Cells(J, "C").Value` of my original script (which works as intended, except it doesn't output subsequent matches onto the next row). But this creates a line break **within** the cell.

Comment: The reason of the error 9 is there is blank cell among the data on col C. I've tested the code w/o any issues against the data in your first comment. Your original script is not reliable to get the correct output. It depends on the order of data on col C.

Comment: I see ... but you have a syntax error on this line `If Len(sKey) > 0` according to to Excel.

Comment: If Len(sKey) > 0 Then

Comment: Works excellently, thank you.