# Incrementing counter starting at 1, if value is same, otherwise reset to 1 when sku is different?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this simple function: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2))&"*")` which is close, but still not exactly working. My data looks like this:

[image]

You can see there are several hyphens ... I need the function to iterate through this column, starting at **Y2** and check for similar values up until the second `-` or `_`. So the desired outcome would be:

[image]

We can ignore everything after the second hyphen or underscore, because that is just meta info on the image type, not related to item sku.

Comment: Are looking for formulas, UDF or Sub ? For VBA, the code `Loop through image col` in your previous post can be used to extract item code from image file name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77881363/how-to-modify-function-so-that-matches-are-appended-in-new-line

Comment: If it is a follow up question, please add a reference link to previous post. I think it's a good option to get the incrementing counter when populate output array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the text is checked from the sixth character onwards for the occurrence of the characters `-`, `_`, and `.` you can apply a formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({"-";"_";"."},A2,6),1)-1)&"*")
```

Answer (score 2):

- It's a good option to get the incrementing counter when populate output array.

Note: The code is revised from [the answer of OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881503/22192445).

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastA As Long, lastC As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, aImg, arrA, arrC
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    Dim iLoc1 As Long, iLoc2 As Long
    lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Load data
    arrA = Range("A1:A" & lastA).Value
    arrC = Range("C1:C" & lastC).Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through image col
    For i = 1 To lastC
        sKey = arrC(i, 1)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            iLoc1 = InStr(1, sKey, "-", vbTextCompare)
            iLoc2 = InStr(1, sKey, "_", vbTextCompare)
            If iLoc1 + iLoc2 = 0 Then
                sKey = Split(sKey, ".")(0)
            Else
                If Len(sKey) - Len(Replace(sKey, "-", "")) > 1 Then
                    iLoc2 = InStrRev(sKey, "-", , vbTextCompare)
                ElseIf iLoc2 = 0 Then
                    iLoc2 = InStrRev(sKey, ".", , vbTextCompare)
                End If
                sKey = Left(sKey, iLoc2 - 1)
            End If
            ' Consolidate by sku name
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrC(i, 1)
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrC(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To lastC, 2)
    iR = 0
    ' Loop through sku name
    For i = 1 To lastA
        sKey = Trim(arrA(i, 1))
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                aImg = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
                For j = 0 To UBound(aImg)
                    iR = iR + 1
                    If j = 0 Then arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                    arrRes(iR, 1) = aImg(j)
                    arrRes(iR, 2) = j + 1
                Next
            Else
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Add new sheet and write output
    Sheets.Add ' optional
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(iR, 3).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, thank you for quick response! However I'm receiving syntax error in VB on this line `sKey = arrC(i, 1)`

Comment: What's the error number and text? Is the layout of source data same as previous? I've tested it w/o issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think `TEXTBEFORE` works best here:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,TEXTBEFORE(A1,{"-","_","."},2)&"*")
```

[image]